# Raspberry pi camera - how do you draw a PIL Image to the preview window?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

The current documentation for rasberry pi says to draw a PIL image onto the camera capture, you do the following:

```
import picamera
from PIL import Image
from time import sleep

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.start_preview()

    # Load the arbitrarily sized image
    img = Image.open('overlay.png')
    # Create an image padded to the required size with
    # mode 'RGB'
    pad = Image.new('RGB', (
        ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
        ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
        ))
    # Paste the original image into the padded one
    pad.paste(img, (0, 0))

    # Add the overlay with the padded image as the source,
    # but the original image's dimensions
    o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tostring(), size=img.size)
    # By default, the overlay is in layer 0, beneath the
    # preview (which defaults to layer 2). Here we make
    # the new overlay semi-transparent, then move it above
    # the preview
    o.alpha = 128
    o.layer = 3

    # Wait indefinitely until the user terminates the script
    while True:
        sleep(1)
```

However, Image.tostring() throws an error with "tostring() has been removed.  Please call tobytes() instead"

What's the correct way to do this given that tostring is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

> However, Image.tostring() throws an error with "tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead"

Simply change:

```
o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tostring(), size=img.size)
```

to:

```
o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tobytes(), size=img.size)
```

The picamera documentation has already been updated to address this: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#overlaying-images-on-the-preview